# Connect .net6 web-service and .net6 wpf application via Azure SignalR

Tags: c#, wpf, azure, signalr, .net-6.0

I'm running a web-Service on Azure which connects to SignalR as following showen:

My Hub-Class:

```
public class ChangeRequest : Hub
{
    protected IHubContext<ChangeRequest> _context;

    public ChangeRequest(IHubContext<ChangeRequest> context) => _context = context;
    public Task? Send(Guid id) =>
        _context.Clients?.All?.SendAsync("SendMessage", id);
}
```

My Programm.cs

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
builder.Services.AddDbContext<CPLopsEntities>(options => options.UseSqlServer(@"Server=tcp:noris.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=CPLopsTest;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=user;Password=!Pw12345;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;"));
builder.Services.AddTransient<ChangeRequest>();

builder.Services.AddSignalR().AddAzureSignalR("Endpoint=https://xxxxxxx.service.signalr.net;AccessKey=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx;Version=1.0;");

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();

app.UseAzureSignalR(r => r.MapHub<ChangeRequest>("/com"));

using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
    scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<CPLopsEntities>().Database.Migrate();

app.Run();
```

When a new Entry is added by calling the web-Service, I call _hub.Send():

```
private readonly CPLopsEntities _context;
private readonly ChangeRequest _hub;
public CompanyController(CPLopsEntities context, ChangeRequest hub)
{
    _context = context;
    _hub = hub;
}

public IActionResult Insert(Entry entry)
{
    Guid newId = CompanyDB.Instance.InsertEntry(entry);
    _hub.Send(newId);
    return Ok();
}
```

Since my Client-Side is a WPF-Application, I did not found quiet a lot information about implementation. What I found so far is this:

```
private const string host = "https://xxxxxxxx.service.signalr.net";
private HubConnection connection;
private Thread thread;
public MainViewModel()
{
    thread = new Thread(() =>
    {
        connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
        .WithUrl(host + "/com")
        .WithAutomaticReconnect()
        .Build();
        
        connection.On<Guid>("ReceiveMessage", g => ExternalLoadCompany(g));
        connection.StartAsync();
    });
    thread.Start();
}

private void ExternalLoadCompany(Guid id)
{
    if (ApiCall.GetCompany(id).Result is Company c)
    {
        Companies.Clear();
        Companies.Add(c);
    }
}
```

So far, my WPF-Application does not recognize any messages sent by the web-Service which makes sense, since I did not authenticate it, however, I found no information about how to pass the full Connectionstring including the AccessKey when trying to register my WPF-App and all information I found so far are blazor-apps or other kind of web-apps.

Answer (score 0):

Your server side code is calling "SendMessage" and the client is looking "ReceiveMessage". The server side is invoking a method on the client and it doesn't exist.

PS: You don't need to start that thread. Task.Run would be better.